# Check if file contains a specific word

Tags: ruby, regex, string, file

In Ruby, how can I check if some file contains some word? I've tried this:

```
foo = File.open('some-file', 'r').read
foo.index(/^word$/)
```

But this won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
File.readlines('some-file').grep(/word/)
```

Remeber that `^` matches against the beginning of a line, and `$` matches against the end of a line. So if you search for `^xyz$` you are really searching for either `xyz\n` (beginning of file) or `\nxyz\n` (somewhere in the middle of the file). No other strings will match.

Comment: Or `\nxyz` at the end of file. Or even `xyz` if it is the entire file.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for a line, which contains *just that word*. Maybe a less constrained search helps:

```
foo.index(/word/)
```

Comment: Is index a member of the File class? I dont see it anywhere

Comment: @Hunter, `foo` is a string (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001142)

Comment: I'm separating words by lines. That solution doesn't work as I expect for few-letter words.

Comment: In this case, `foo` is the result of a `read`, so it's a string.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I didn't notice the read() call at the end of the line

Comment: can I plug in `File.readlines('some-file').grep(/word/)` into logical IF as is ? Tried and it doesn't work